# spring maven clean package not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-security, ubuntu-16.04

I have used stater.spring.io and web, spring security, jpa as dependencies. Downloaded the zip file and unzip and export it as an external maven project. When I do the same thing is windows, it works just fine but when the same thing in linux I get the following error "`Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.3 from/to spring-ext (http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/): unexpected end of stream on Connection{repo.spring.io:80, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=repo.spring.io/35.186.232.213:80 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}" I have tried forced maven updating the project but it doesn't do process more than one percent and it stuck showing this link http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/` in the in the maven console. I have tried ubuntu terminal and but has the same problem.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final

org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:329)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:504)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:530)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:492)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:496)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:351)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:298)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:405)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:352)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1351)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:349)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:77)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.3 from/to spring-ext (http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/): unexpected end of stream on Connection{repo.spring.io:80, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=repo.spring.io/35.186.232.213:80 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:177)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.importDependencyManagement(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1192)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:455)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:421)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:411)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.importDependencyManagement(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1226)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:455)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:421)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:411)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
... 37 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.3 from/to spring-ext (http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/): unexpected end of stream on Connection{repo.spring.io:80, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=repo.spring.io/35.186.232.213:80 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:173)
... 46 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.3 from/to spring-ext (http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/): unexpected end of stream on Connection{repo.spring.io:80, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=repo.spring.io/35.186.232.213:80 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:895)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:673)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:310)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
... 49 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{repo.spring.io:80, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=repo.spring.io/35.186.232.213:80 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:205)
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:75)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.execute(OkHttpAetherClient.java:207)
at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.head(OkHttpAetherClient.java:122)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.resourceExist(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:492)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:446)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:304)
... 51 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:226)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:210)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
... 71 more
pom.xml /secure line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following Steps to solve the problem:

1. Right click on the project folder ->Maven ->  Update Project -> turn on force update the snapshots/releases
2. After the update is done then Right click on the project folder -> Run as -> Maven clean
3. Then Right click on the project folder -> Run as -> Maven install

Then the error is gone